# Why do JPA-generated update queries include more fields than necessary?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa-2.0

This may be a very stupid question, but...

I'm using JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 4. I have a persistent object, with many fields.

I create and persist it in one transaction. Then, in another, I look that object up and change the value of one field on it:

```
try{
    tx.begin();
    MyObj object = myObjDAO.findById(objectId);
    object.setFieldA("Different value");
} finally {
    tx.commit();
}
```

JPA persists this change when the transaction commits, but I can see from my MySQL genquery.log that the update statement it generates involves all fields on the object:

> 439 Query
>   /* update uk.co.core.objects.MyObj */ update myobj set created='2012-03-06 13:39:37', modified='2012-03-06 13:39:37', version=1, fieldA='Different value', fieldB='originalValue', fieldC='originalValue' where id='objectId' and version=0;
>   439 Query     commit

Why does it include all the unchanged fields and their existing values in the query, rather than just:

> update myobj set fieldA='different value', version=1, modified='somedate' where id='objectId' and version=0;

It may not look like much of a difference on this example, but I have some objects with many more fields, all of which are included in their update statements.

Would it not be faster/more efficient, even if purely from a volume of string data perspective, to only include changed fields in the update query? If so, is there a configuration option to make it do so?

Hope you can help anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure hibernate to **exclude the unmodified fields in the update query** as told in this [article](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/).

This is done by adding `dynamic-update="true"` in your class mapping.

```
<class ... table="your_table" .... dynamic-update="true">
```

In a large table with many columns (legacy design) or contains large data volumes, this will have a great impact on the system performance.

It can have some performance impact as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405560/507864). So measure the performance of your code before you implement it.

Read the API [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

To persist just the delta's your ORM would have to:

1. Read the current version of your object, with all it's sub-entities,
   from the database.
2. Iterate each attribute and compare their value to see if it has
   changed.
3. Generate a specialized query just for updating the attributes that
   were changed.

That's significantly more complicated than just issuing a standard update across all columns, and would also be significantly *less* performant, due to the increased complexity.

Comment: a specialized a **HQL** is a good idea, when you know exactly what to update, regardless of the version. But am afraid your solution might be a **performance overhead as the object has to loaded to memory and then should be compared**.

Answer (score 0):

Now discovered the danger of asking 2 questions in the same... question. Both ManuPK and Perception gave great, helpful, correct answers. However I received more info and understanding from ManuPk's, hence why I accepted it.

Definitely agree with him - setting the attribute should only be done for certain tables, and performance should definitely be tested before and after.

In future, I'll try to make my questions more targeted.