# Why in JPA Hibernate update query ; all attributes get update in SQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA with Hibernate. When I modify one attribute of an object and update it; the generated SQL shows all the columns getting updated ! Why doesn't it update only the modified columns? Is there a way to achieve that because I feel that will be more optimized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default hibernate includes all the fields in the update query. If you want to exclude this either use **a custom update HQL** or you can configure hibernate to **exclude the unmodified fields in the update query** as told in this [article](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/).

This is done by adding `dynamic-update="true"` in your class mapping.

```
<class ... table="your_table" .... dynamic-update="true">
```

In a large table with many columns (legacy design) or contains large data volumes, this will have a great impact on the system performance. It can have some performance impact as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405560/507864). So measure the performance of your code before you implement it.

Read the API [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class) for more information.

If you are using annotations,

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(selectBeforeUpdate=true)
```

It is a hibernate specific annotation, and not available in JPA. Here is a good [article](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2009/10/22/some-useful-options-in-class-element-in-hibernate/) linking to the details.

Comment: This works fine when using hibernate only. But I am using JPA hence I use only persistence.xml and NOT hibernate.properties. I make all declarations of my enties in persistence.xml like <class>com.kids.domain.Child</class> and there I am not able to use this flag

Comment: @Deepak: Sorry for the delay, I have updated the answer with the details.

Comment: I wonder why the Hibernate team chose to update all columns by default

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem for the last 4-5 days which was slowly driving me mad.

A delete operation was using ALL columns instead of just the primary key column.

Eg.

```
DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID=? AND NAME=? AND VALUE=?
```

When I removed the "dynamicUpdate=true" annotation, Hibernate started generating the right SQL, ie.

```
DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID=?
```

It was causing nasty issues on Oracle 11g, when `VALUE` was a CLOB.