# JPA Hibernate updates an entity but there are no any changes in the DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In short, I have three methods:

```
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, noRollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void Manage(long bookId) throws Exception {

        Book book = dao.getByKey(bookId);

        //...

        register(book);

    }


    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, noRollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void register(Book book) {

        try {

            // updateSomeId method should be called in another thread
            // POST request to the service, waiting for the response then updating the DB
            Runnable task = () -> {

                if(someId > 0) {
                    dao.updateSomeId(book, someId);

            }
            Thread thread = new Thread(task);
            thread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }



    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, noRollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void updateSomeId(Book book, long someId) {
        try {
            Book findedBook = getByKey(book.getBookId());
            findedBook.setSomeId(someId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error", e);
        }
    }
```

`updateSomeId` method must update the `someId` property in Book table.
In the log I see:
`Hibernate: update Book set author=?, someId=? where bookId=?`

But, there are no any changes in my DB, no any errors. Could anyone explain what happens and how to solve it?
**It's one of thousands of updates I have and only in this case it hasn't updated the DB table.**

**JPA 2.1**

**Hibernate 5.2.10.Final**

Comment: Do you see the query in the DB log? What parameters are substituted into the query - do they match those that you expect? Do you see a `COMMIT` statement in the DB log?

Comment: The problem is likely that transactions don't generally propagate across multiple threads. Why do you feel you need to perform part of the work on a separate thread, though? Judging by the code you posted, it doesn't make much sense. If you don't want the client of `Manage` to block waiting for the method to finish, data access layer is not where you want to handle async execution

Comment: @Boris the Spider, it's impossible now...

Comment: @crizzis, I need to perform part of the work on a separate thread because I've simplified the logic in the question. In fact I send POST request to other service there and I should not wait the response, but when I receive the response I need to update the DB.

Comment: In that case: (1) sending a request is an irreversible operation, why should it be a part of the transaction? Most likely, you should schedule sending the request *after* the transaction commits *and then* call `updateSomeId` in a separate transaction altogether, (2) if you insist that the request happens inside the transaction, then you should make `Manage` *completely synchronous*. It's the calling code's job to schedule the execution of `Manage` on a separate thread

Answer (score 0):

May be your main thread is not waiting the update task thread. Therefore container cannot commit your transaction. Can you change your register method like below and give it a try?

```
   @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, noRollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void register(Book book) {

        try {

            // updateSomeId method should be called in another thread
            Runnable task = () -> {

                if(someId > 0) {
                    dao.updateSomeId(book, someId);

            }
            Thread thread = new Thread(task);
            thread.start();
            thread.join();//this tells the main thread to wait until it finishes execution.

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes, the main thread is not waiting the update task thread and after the task was started the main thread responses to another service. I was debugging my code and in this case I saw that the data was updated although the main thread has already stopped. I have to create separate thread because it really nesessery here and I should not wait the task will be stopped.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to update `someId` field alone in `findedBook` object but in log `Hibernate: update Book set author=?, someId=? where bookId=?` update statement shows multiple fields `author=?, someId=?`, seems the logged statement is not meant for your current operation.

- Create new method in dao class with statement as `session.update(book)`  and call the same method from `updateSomeId` method and pass `book` object as parameter.

Comment: By default hibernate includes all the fields in the update query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315377/why-in-jpa-hibernate-update-query-all-attributes-get-update-in-sql
In my case, I've checked many times the log and it's exactly that operation I'm interested in.

Comment: Without dynamic updates Hibernate will use prepared statements that update all fields.