# How do I update a certain field of a Model in Playframework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

Suppose we have a User class, if I want to update it's name:

User user = User.findById(123);
   user.name = "someone";
   user.save();

The generated SQL would be

```
update user as user0 set user0.name = ? user0.email = ? .....
```

That means `Play` didn't realize I just want to update a single field. Is there any way could make the generated SQL only update the specified fields ?

Comment: tag your question with proper Play version and ORM used

Comment: next time write precisely which version(s) you are using at the begining! Current stable version of Play is ver. 2+ so if not specified other version we assume you are asking in its context.

Answer (score 1):

**Info: this is answer for Play 2 + Ebean! so it DOES NOT work with Play 1 + JPA**

There are some options in [Ebean's API](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/index.html), so you should check it and choose one:

- [`Update<T>`](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Update.html) - check in the sample for `@NamedUpdates` annotation
- [`Ebean.createUpdate(beanType, updStatement)`](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Ebean.html#createUpdate%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [`SqlUpdate`](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlUpdate.html) - you can just perform raw SQL update, without need for giving the entity type

Comment: Wrong guess, it seems to be Play 1. ;)

Comment: yeap, he added that tag after my answer, bad luck :D

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on whether Play (or actually Avaje Ebean) actually tracks which of the fields are changed. It's simpler to update all of the fields instead.

This isn't an issue performance-wise either, so I wouldn't waste too much time looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hibernate's dynamic update feature : http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/

But remember that this have negative impact on performance as database cannot cache statements. See here for others explanations : [Hibernate : dynamic-update dynamic-insert - Performance Effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404630/hibernate-dynamic-update-dynamic-insert-performance-effects)