# How to enter SQL instruction in controller with play 2 and java

Tags: java, sql, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm developing a web application with [Play 2.1.0](http://www.playframework.com/) and programming it with Java and I need to have access to data already saved in a DB to modify them.

I tried to create a new instance without the `new` operator and reference it to my object saved in the database, but even if there is no pointer error, it won't change values of attributes. I couldn't figure out why, so I've decided to enter SQL queries directly.

Same thing, it does not seems to have any mistake, but it won't change anything... I think this comes from a bad link to the database :

Here is my code in `application.java` :

```
public static Result modifyQuestionnaire(Long id) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = null;
    Connection con = DB.getConnection();

    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String query = "SELECT * FROM WOQ.questionnaire WHERE id=id";
        ResultSet uprs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        uprs.updateString("name", "baba");
        uprs.updateRow();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stmt!=null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
    }
return redirect(routes.Application.questionnaire(id));
}
```

And I also try to enter an `UPDATE` query directly, still the same..

I've looked everywhere and did not find any solution (except Anorm but it seems to work with Scala language)

Btw, if anyone knows a solution with a second instance that refers to the same object (it seems possible but as I say, there is no error but no actions neither), it's fine for me.

Comment: Didn't you consider using delivered `Ebean` ORM ? it has methods for raw queries for selecting and also updating DB's rows

Comment: Hello, I'm using ebean to create my tables (with Questionnaire.java for instance) but I don't know what you mean by using delivered Ebean ORM.. Could you enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, you showed as that you are trying to create totally new connection, so I supposed, that you don't want to use Ebean, but in case when you are already use it, you can just use its methods for the task:

([*copied*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442462/1066240)) There are some options in Ebean's API, so you should check it and choose one:

- [`Update<T>`](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Update.html) - check in the sample for `@NamedUpdates` annotation
- [`Ebean.createUpdate(beanType, updStatement)`](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Ebean.html#createUpdate%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [`SqlUpdate`](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlUpdate.html) - you can just perform raw SQL update, without need for giving the entity type

Comment: And do you know the best way to create an object with an attribute that is a list of other objects, in order to have access to this list with SQL requests?

Because with the oneToMany, I can't see my list anywhere, so I can't do any sql requests on it...

Comment: Doesn't this relation create join table for relation ? (I don't remember now) in such case you can collect data using common SQL JOINS.