# Can I update or set only one entity field via hibenrate Session.load without loading entire object?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-session

The hibernate [session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) has [load](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load(java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable)) method for retrieving a proxy without loading entire object, this is often uses when it is need to link parent and child entity. But what about updating proxy? For example:

```
 MyEntity entity = session.load(MyEntity.class, 1l);
 entity.setName("newName");
 session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
```

It is expected here that only `name` column will be updated for entity with `id=1l` without loading entire entity. Is it true? Does this piece of code equals to sql execution like `UPDATE MyEntity SET name = 'newName' where id = 1` or not?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is no equals by default. But it's possible to do it with Hibernate and it's called dynamic update. You can enable it via [DynamicUpdate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicUpdate.html) annotation or via property of the [Entity](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Entity.html#dynamicUpdate--) annotation(note: it's deprecated)

But in both cases, there are some limitations, like the one, that you have to fetch your entity first.

You can find a number of examples over internet, [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/) is one of them. And here is one [related article](http://www.nonfunc.com/2016/02/15/performance-impact-of-using-hibernate-dynamicinsert-and-dynamicupdate/) and one more SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404630/hibernate-dynamic-update-dynamic-insert-performance-effects) about perfomance of dynamic updates.